# Setting which pages can be accessed in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I've put a considerable amount of digging into this but I haven't been able to figure out what the best method would be.

I have an employee management system where everyone who logs in is either an "employee", a "supervisor" or a "manager".

At the moment, I display different versions of pages just fine depending on what their rank is. However, regular "employees" can still get to pages they shouldn't if they manually enter the URL. According to CakePHP's documentation, it says all pages are restricted by default, and you have to grant access to each one. But I haven't granted access and it seems all the pages are accessible.

What is the best method for page access?
Thanks!

Edit: Here is the configuration of the AppController:

```
   public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'Employee'
                )
            ),
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'employees',
                'action' => 'login',
                //'plugin' => 'users'
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => 'You must be logged in to see that.'
        )
    );
```

And then there is the isAuthorized() method which always is set to return false:

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
// Any registered user can access public functions
/*if (empty($this->request->params['admin'])) {
    return true;
}*/

// Only admins can access admin functions
/*if (isset($this->request->params['admin'])) {
    return (bool)($user['role'] === 'admin');
}*/

// Default deny
return false;
}
```

Comment: How are users authenticating? Are you using Auth?

Comment: Yes, I am using Auth in CakePHP 2. Their system role or "rank" is stored in the users table.

Comment: Can you show your Auth setup code?

Comment: I'll post it as an Edit above. Also, my application uses an Employees table instead of a Users table, but it is the same functionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crete two tables in database

1. resources (id, controller, action) (This will contain controller names and action names.)
2. permission (roll_id, resource_id)

In `isAuthorized()` function

1. If roll is `admin`, then return true.
2. Else Check the following.
3. using `$this->request->controller` Get current controller name.
4. using `$this->request->action` Get current action name.
5. Get `resource_id` from `resources` table for current controller and action.
6. Check record in `permission` table for `resource_id` and `roll_id`.
7. If record exist then return true.
8. Else at the end it is returning false by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing this in the AppController.php

```
    class AppController extends Controller {

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => ['fields' => ['username' => 'email']]
            ],
            'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        ]);

        //some other code here    
    }
```